# cant type in an EditText android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/horizontalPadding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/horizontalPadding"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/verticalPadding"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/verticalPadding">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding" >

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/training_exercise_set_weight"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/training_exercise_set_weight"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

When my app is running the keyboard is visible and clickable, but the value of editText doesn't change. how can i resolve it?

Comment: don't spam with irrelevant tags

Comment: Why are you using  android:layout_weight="1" while you have not set weightSum in parent

Comment: Because why not? each will take a half of the screen, what's the problem ? @KhizarHayat

Comment: @Davide android:inputType="numberDecimal" will allow only numerical inputs include '.'. Make sure you are pressing keys between 0 to 9 not alphabets.

Comment: @KevalPatel i pressing only number but the value doesn't change

Comment: @Davide Can you post a screen shot?

Comment: this is the screenshot of my app ( http://it.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=ntksp&s=9#.V5Xb_LiLS1s ) The problem is that when i click on the edit text appear the keybord with only numbers for 1 sec and after re-appear the keyboard that you see in the screenshot.

Comment: @Davide Are you using a TextWatcher?

Comment: @KNeerajLal i'm using 
    weight.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener()  
where weight is my EditText

Answer (score 1):

If someone is interesed, i resolved using the EditText.requestFocus()

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `android:ems="10"` with `android:maxEms="10"` or `android:maxLength="10"`, I'm not sure, what you want to achieve with this parameter

Hope, this will solve you issue

Answer (score 0):

`android:ems="10"` is all about *width* of the view, however you are overriding this setting by `layout_width` property setting to `match_parent`.

It looks like you would want two `EditText`s to be stretch equally and fill that `LinearLayout`, so here you wouldn't need `ems` at all. You would need `maxLength` instead.

Also note that to stretch those `EditText`s you should set their widths to `0dp` and set their weight to `1` (or something else. They should be equal).

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding" >

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/training_exercise_set_weight"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/training_exercise_set_weight"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:maxLength="10" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it doesn't work, the problem is the same. The keyboard is visible but it don't edit the value of editText

Comment: @Davide In your code, do you attach a `TextWatcher` to this `EditText`?

Comment: this is my java code

weight.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

Comment: @Davide Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38563253/edit) your question and add your Java code there.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was, I didn't let my PopupWindow be focused. Then I found out that my PopupWindow focusable was by default set to false. So, I try to add 1 new parameter that explicitly tells the PopupWindow is focusable. You can see it in my screenshot below. Previously I didn't pass the false value, only the first three values.

[image: PopupWindow focusable]

Now, I can type anything in the EditText. This one took a whole day to be resolved.